# Specify dynamic shape as an input argument

Tags: python, tensorflow

For tensorflow functions that require a shape argument, how can we feed a dynamic shape as one of the input argument(s)?

For instance, let's say I have a placeholder

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
```

And now I want to create a 1D random tensor with the same shape as the first dimension of `x`.

```
r = tf.random_uniform([x.get_shape()[0]])
```

This will not work since `x.get_shape()[0]` will return a static shape "None". Is there a a way to assign a dynamic shape to `r` based on the dynamic shape of `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the dynamic shape of a tensor using the [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) op, and use that as the argument to `tf.random_uniform()`:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
r = tf.random_uniform(tf.shape(x)[0:1])
```

(Note that the slice of `tf.shape(x)`, i.e. `[0:1]` must specify a range rather than a single element, because `tf.random_uniform()` expects a vector of dimensions.)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3])
s = tf.shape(x)
s2 = tf.slice(s, [0], [1])
r = tf.random_uniform(s2)
sess = create_session()
print r.eval(feed_dict={x:np.ones((4,3))})
```

> [ 0.69890845  0.64149153  0.16378665  0.89732885]